# Search multiple tables for the same value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MYSQL database with a few tables, all of which have the same structure. I want to search all the tables to find a row with a specific value for a column. Do I have to search the tables one by one or there is an easier way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can union all tables. You still need traverse all tables one by one, but in case of `union` you will not have cartesian multiplication, hence best from all:

```
SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE column = 'value'
UNION ALL
SELECT column FROM table2 WHERE column = 'value'
;
```

Comment: what to do if columns are different in the 2 tables? Because: 'UNION must have the same number of columns'

Comment: Use something like:
SELECT column1 AS col FROM table1 ...
UNION ALL
SELECT column2 AS col FROM table2 ...

Answer (score 4):

Easily done and ALSO TESTED IN MYSQL WORKBENCH.

SELECT ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two;
```

SELECT ONE VALUE FROM TWO TABLES:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE field = 'some_val'
```

SELECT MULTIPLE VALUES FROM TWO TABLES:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE field = 'some_val' AND field2 = 'some_val' AND field3 = 'some_val'
```

Comment: I think that better use union, because separate tables by comma it is cartesian multiplication, and union - no, even if you use union all...

Comment: Um.  No.  Works for me.

Comment: @StephenCarr is correct, The only thing i'd probably do differently is assign aliases to each table, that way you can search for values within uniquely named columns

Comment: even though it works, but performance wise that's a really bad answer. As @VladimirKovpak mentioned, selecting from two or more tables causes cartesian multiplication. So if you have 1000 records on each table, it makes your record set size of 1 000 000. I recommend not to use this approach if performance matters. Take a look at solutions with UNION.

Comment: @Jokūbas Completely agree with you! Moreover, I have answer with union example, but it was downvoted((( Don't know why(((

Comment: will this work in sql server? I've tried it but it gives me an error for the field stating that it is an ambiguous column name

Answer (score 0):

I don't understanding how FIRST I select city :product list will appare from city , next find product search , how I bring search all from same city which I select previous one automatically?
Pls support on php.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).