# Search multiple tables for the same value and get table where result it comes from

Tags: mysql

For the first part of my question, I have found an old question that is similar and has an accepted answer but the solution does not work -> [Search multiple tables for the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352159/search-multiple-tables-for-the-same-value)

So the accepted answer says:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE field = 'some_val'
```

When I have tried that I have got this error

> Column 'field' in where clause is ambiguous

I have tried to solve that using:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_one,
    table_two
WHERE
    table_one.field = 'some_val'
OR table_two.field = 'some_val';
```

That solves the above error but the result is: nothing from table_one and all entries from table_two

**I have to clarify that in my test the value to find 'some_val' it exists in table_one and not exist in table_two**

So this has been for the first part of my question.

**The second part.**

Assuming there will be the solution for the first part, the second part of the question would be:

How to check where does the result come from? ... Where 'some_val' has been found? (in table_one in table_two or both) ?

Comment: use `union` for make a query , share your table structure with sqlfiddle , i'll make query according your structure

Comment: You are right ... and that solve both of mi problems because I can add for each union one indicator: Ex (Select *, 'table_one' as found_on FROM ... etc ) UNION (SELECT *, 'table_two' as found_on ... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use union for your problem.You can find more details regarding `union` in [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
SELECT
    table_one.col_1,
    table_one.col_2,
    'table_one' AS from_table
FROM
    table_one
WHERE
    table_one.field = 'some_val'
UNION
    SELECT
        table_two.col_1,
        table_two.col_2,
        'table_two' AS from_table
    FROM
        table_two
    WHERE
        table_two.field = 'some_val'
```