# SQL query on 3 tables, one with different column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables;

projects, campaigns, clients.

I need to return results from all 3 tables where the searchterm matches. However, I need to check against 'name' column in projects and campaigns tables, but 'description' column in the clients table. NB This is an existing client database, I have no authority to change the the column names.

Example: user searches for 'data', I need to SELECT:

```
name as title FROM projects WHERE name LIKE %data%,

name as title FROM campaigns WHERE name LIKE %data%
```

AND

```
description as title FROM clients WHERE description LIKE %data%
```

I'm struggling to combine the queries. Below is what I have so far, which returns a syntax error. I am also thinking I may be taking the wrong approach.

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    c.name,
    cl.description AS title
FROM
    projects,
    campaigns,
    clients
WHERE
    p.name LIKE % DATA %
OR c.name LIKE % DATA %
OR cl.description LIKE % DATA %
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327255/search-multiple-tables-for-the-same-value-and-get-table-where-result-it-comes-fr/45327692#45327692

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search multiple tables for the same value and get table where result it comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327255/search-multiple-tables-for-the-same-value-and-get-table-where-result-it-comes-fr)

Comment: check given link for solution

Comment: Dude don't do this. Please! bring the whole table data to your code update it on every crude operation, then handle your search there for better performance.

Comment: So, for the purposes of this query, you're not interested in any relationshiop that may exist between the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `union all`:

```
SELECT name as title FROM projects WHERE name LIKE %data%,
UNION ALL
SELECT name as title FROM campaigns WHERE name LIKE %data%
UNION ALL
SELECT description as title FROM clients WHERE description LIKE %data%;
```

If you want to remove duplicates, then use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks - duplicates meaning the actual result that would be returned is identical in two or more tables?

Comment: @CIvemy . . . If you want to ensure that `name` is not duplicated in the result set, then use `union`.  If you know there are no duplicates or you want them, then use `union all`.